# Android WebView and Laravel login error

Tags: android, laravel, cookies, webview

I have a Laravel application with login.
It all works fine in a browser, but if I use Android `WebView`, and try to login, I get an error

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

This is because, when I try and get the user with `Auth::user()`; it returns `null`.

I am logging my user in using auth()->login($user) in a function. If I `dd($user)` at this step, it does get the correct user - but then I redirect into `/dashboard` which then fires a function, where the first thing it does is to try and get the `user`.
Its at this point it breaks.

This all works in a browser - also in an android browser. But not in `Webview`.
Can this have anything to do with the `session cookie` or something? Is it possible to try and `dd()` the `session cookie` to see if it exists?
And if it doesn't, how come this isn't setting in Android `Webview`?

I have tried using `CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);` but this isn't helping, and should also be defined by default.

All help appreciated